# Using proxy in .htaccess help display specific URL without redirection

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, proxy

I need to display a specific page from a WordPress blog (URL `http://blog.site.com/blog/home/`) in a specific folder (`http://blog.site.com/blog2`) without changing the URL.

I'm using this code in the .htaccess:

```
<proxy http://blog.site.com/blog/home/>
       Allow from all
</proxy>
ProxyPass /blog2 http://blog.site.com/blog/home/
ProxyPassReverse /blog2 http://blog.site.com/blog/home/
```

But it displays a page not found error.

Does someone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You don't appear to need mod_proxy for this - is there a specific reason that you are? Can't you simply use an internal rewrite?

Comment: Hm... Possibly, but I was looking through solutions online and came upon someone suggesting using proxy. I've tried rewrite, but all I can achieve is changing the URL, which I want to avoid. :-)

Comment: "I'm using this code in the .htaccess:" - There is also the issue that these (mod_proxy) directives cannot be set in .htaccess - they can only be set in your server config. (I'm surprised you aren't getting a 500 error?) Do you have your own server?

Comment: yes, it's a dedicated server and mod_proxy is working.